# Dynamically set javax.portlet.faces.defaultViewId.view depending on user group

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, liferay-6

Suppose you have a JSF portlet, where users from different UserGroups are logging in. And you want to check their userGroup and let them land on different Facelets pages, instead of the one stated in portlet.xml

```
<init-param>
    <name>javax.portlet.faces.defaultViewId.view</name>
    <value>/html/users/userView.xhtml</value>
    <!-- 
        <value>/html/admins/adminView.xhtml</value> 
    -->
</init-param>
```

Actually I have a more complex business Logic, so I created a method on a managed Bean that decides on which page the user should land.

What would be the best way to manage their landing page, other than creating a different portlet (different landing page) for each UserGroup ?

I'm using primefaces 3.5 and Liferay 6.1.0 ga1, if that helps

---

EDIT: Just to make myself more clear, I don't specifically need to change the `javax.portlet.faces.defaultViewId.view`, although I thought of that too. Anything that lets me land the user on a different page, based on the outcome of a bean's method, would be OK

If this was another page, I would call an action that returns the page as String, but since this is the first portlet page, I just can't find a way to interrupt my bean's method

Comment: thanx for your edit @BalusC. Just to make sure, I don't specifically need to change the *javax.portlet.faces.defaultViewId.view* (although I tried that too). Anything that lets me land the user on a different page, based on the outcome of a bean's method, would be OK

Comment: It gives the Liferay users a better understanding what exactly you want by just glancing over the question title :) I don't do Liferay, but in "plain JSF/Facelets" perspective it would be possible to have a generic landing page with a bean which runs on `preRenderView` and redirects accordingly. But again, there may be a better Liferay-specific way to achieve the same.

Comment: I tried <f:event listener="#{...}" type="preRenderView" />, and the bean method was called, but this would not fetch the new page (it's called with ajax='true', isn't it ?? ). I'd love to see this work with preRenderView, besides, I'd rather not use a Liferay-specific approach.

Comment: Use `ExternalContext#redirect()`. It's capable of recognizing ajax requests and returning the appropriate redirect instruction via XML.

Comment: Nice, I forgot the .redirect() option. I'll try that!